# JavaScript - How to extract strings - keys/values from response using RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am very new to regex, and I want to extract some data from API responses.

I have a response from my API call:

```
{
  server: 'nginx/1.21.0',
  date: 'Mon, 25 Apr 2022 11:34:20 GMT',
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  'x-powered-by': 'PHP/7.4.16',
  expires: 'Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT',
  'cache-control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, private, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'content-security-policy': "frame-ancestors 'self';",
  'set-cookie': [
    'SSESS8b04132f4690dc8ceb7837d5134a5519=ZbgVsmpp6DBRWwNCRMm5DTpfEoKffsNM7l8ILoCWkug; path=/; domain=test.net; secure; HttpOnly',
    'su=1; expires=Thu, 22-Apr-2032 11:34:20 GMT; Max-Age=315360000; path=/; domain=test.net',
    'lt=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; test.net',
    'dtCookie=v_4_srv_10_sn_6364C36040ADFF47B91A838BB8B2CADD_perc_100000_ol_0_mul_1_app-3Aea7c4b59f27d43eb_1; Path=/; Domain=test.net',
    '870be6fb89fc78ad2ca0eca3828e3019=7055c78f3c2b7311a5c77934caad6939; path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None'
  ],
  'x-oneagent-js-injection': 'true',
  'x-ruxit-js-agent': 'true',
  'server-timing': 'dtSInfo;desc="0", dtRpid;desc="493206686"',
  connection: 'close'
}
```

I want to extract **SSESS8b04132f4690dc8ceb7837d5134a5519** & **ZbgVsmpp6DBRWwNCRMm5DTpfEoKffsNM7l8ILoCWkug** which are variables, and every single run that are different values.

I manage to construct a group that is capturing the whole key/value, but still when I try to console it, doesn't work.

https://regex101.com/r/2dKW4s/1

try1 as:

```
var matches1 = loginModern.headers.match(new RegExp("(SSESS.*)=(.+?);\s*path"));
console.log(matches1[2]);
    
result output: TypeError: loginModern.headers.match is not a function
```

try2:

```
const regex1 = new RegExp('(SSESS.*)=(.+?);\s*path');
var matches1 = regex1.exec(loginModern.headers)
console.log(matches1);

null
```

How to fetch `SSESS8b04132f4690dc8ceb7837d5134a5519` & `ZbgVsmpp6DBRWwNCRMm5DTpfEoKffsNM7l8ILoCWkug`
from the above response, having in mind they are changing variables?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `loginModern.headers.match is not a function` Is loginModern.headers an array? Perhaps use a json parser to get the property first and then parse the value?

Comment: Can you fix the API to return proper JSON, so you don't need to write your own parser?

Comment: If `loginModern.headers` returns the object you posted above, you need to access the `set-cookie` property. `loginModern.headers['set-cookie']`. Then find the right string from the array. If `loginModern.headers` return a string, you can use `JSON.parse` to convert it to an object

Comment: I think loginModern.headers is returning a proper JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jwdgmp

```
const setCookieArray = loginModern.headers["set-cookie"];
const stringContainingSSESS = setCookieArray.find((item) =>
  item.includes("SSESS")
);

const matches = stringContainingSSESS.match(/(SSESS[a-zA-Z0-9]*)=(.+?);/);

console.log("key", matches[1]);
console.log("value", matches[2]);
```

I ran the [regexp](https://regex101.com/r/imm9IM/1) you provided against the `loginModern.headers` and it had some issues matching up. This [regexp](https://regex101.com/r/zOhyCP/1) is more accurate

Comment: Thanks Amats, this works perfectly fine. But, is it possible with a single matcher, without accessing set-cookie property?

Comment: @vlatko606 If you look at the sandbox, you should see an example of the code that you're looking for. It only requires that you turn the `loginModern.headers` JSON into a string with `JSON.stringify` and then you can run the match. Please refer to the definition of `matches2` in the linked sandbox

Comment: Thanks for that. even though I use: const book = JSON.stringify(loginModern.headers); and then after, const regex1 = new RegExp('(SSESS.*)=(.+?);\s*path');
var matches1 = regex1.exec(book)
console.log(matches1);  I got: null   what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @vlatko606 I updated the sandbox to use regex.exec, it's working fine. Can you try using this regexp /(SSESS[a-zA-Z0-9]*)=(.+?);/. I also updated the answer with a comparison of the results from both regexp values

Comment: which answer did you updated, is it the one that I placed( try1 & try2), or the one that you did? Coz I cant see any update since the initial answer of mine.

Comment: @vlatko606 click the regexp hyperlinks in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244251/discussion-between-vlatko606-and-amats).